# Outbound URLRewrite rule not replacing properly

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I have an IIS 10 reverse proxy set up which proxies content from `backend.example.com/pages` to `www.example.com/`. The inbound rules are working properly and the page is being proxied, but the rule to rewrite the URLs in the page isn't working properly. These are the cases and results I have observed:

Case 1:
Pattern: `^(href.*?)backend.example.com/pages(/?.*)`
Rewrite: `{R:1}{R:2}`
Result: `https://backend.example.com/pages/page1` -> `https://www.example.com/pages/page1` (It shouldn't have the `/pages`)

Case 2:
Pattern: `^(href.*?)pages(/?.*)`
Rewrite: `{R:1}{R:2}`
Result: `https://backend.example.com/pages/page1` -> `https://pages/` (Is missing the entire hostname)

Case 3:
Pattern: `^(href.*?)pages(/?.*)`
Rewrite: `{R:1}{R:2}`
Result: `https://backend.example.com/pages/page1` -> `https://backend.example.com/backend.example.com/pages/`(Repeats hostname as first subdirectory)

I'm really not sure exactly how to tweak this, any help as appreciated.

Comment: How does `()` in an expression capture the contents from the input and fill up `{R:N}`? That's almost just a question about regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comment, this ended up being a regex issue; using `(href.*?)/pages(/?.*)` and `{R:1}{R:2}` worked.